# Escape sequences in virtual terminal

Tags: windows-7, terminal, putty, escape-characters, com

I need send next escape sequence through COM port.

```
^[[LD
```

> **NOTE (from manual) Pressing "Ctrl-v", "Ctrl-[" on keyboard will generate the "^[" escape sequence. In some file systems, the escape
>   sequences may not appear on the serial console but the input will
>   still reach the character LCD.**

Which combinations of keyboard's buttons should I use to generate above-stated escape sequence? 
Which virtual terminals need I use for this purpose? I have PuTTy and TeraTerm in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[` represents the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> keys, and is also equivalent to <kbd>Esc</kbd> on VT100-compatible terminals. The rest – `[LD` – are just literal characters.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to send the sequence in PuTTY, TeraTerm or any other terminal emulator.

(Another version is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.)

Answer (score 0):

Teraterm has script language you can use. send 31 will send an escape. I suspect you can  assign macros to function keys.